# how do we handle form group password match in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

How do we handle if password match in angular 11 betweem 2 input fields ? user will input from password frield and if the user input on the second field it should show message if match or error . Any idea guys ?

#ts

```
this.signupForm = this.fb.group({
      password: [
        '',
        [
          this.validatePasswordRequired,
          this.validateMinimumPassword,
          this.validatePasswordUpperCase,
          this.validatePasswordLowerCase,
          this.validatePasswordSpecialCharacter,
          this.validateOneNumber
        ]
      ],
      passwordConfirm:[
        Validators.required
      ]
    });
```

#html

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>New password</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="password" type="{{(showPassword === false)?'password':'text'}}">
            <mat-icon matSuffix style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="toggleShowPassword()">
              {{!showPassword?'visibility':'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
            <mat-error *ngIf="password.hasError('required')">
              {{errFormMsg.REQUIRED}}
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="passwordConfirm" type="{{(showPassword === false)?'password':'text'}}">
            <mat-icon matSuffix style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="toggleShowPassword()">
              {{!showPassword?'visibility':'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
            <mat-error *ngIf="password.hasError('required')">
              {{errFormMsg.REQUIRED}}
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you have already defined custom Validators.
You can just add another Validator on passwordConfirm which checks for equality. In the validator, just get the value from the first and compare it to the current.

Add this Function in the ts.

```
equalWithPasswordValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const equal = control.value === this.signupForm.get("password").value;
    return equal ? {notEqual: {value: "Passwords do not match"}} : null;
  };
}
```

And Add this to your FormGroup Creation

```
passwordConfirm:[ '',
        [Validators.required, this.equalWithPasswordValidator]
      ]
```

In the html add something similar to this

```
<mat-error *ngIf="signupForm.get('passwordConfirm').hasError('notEqual')">
              <!-- your Error Message -->
</mat-error>
```

Comment: Sir , would you integrate your answer to my sample code ?

Comment: *ngIf="signupForm.get('passwordConfirm').hasError('required')" works but *ngIf="signupForm.get('passwordConfirm').hasError('notEqual')" does not work

Comment: how do we trigger the error on submit only ?